# jQuery show/hide div not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sub menu div which has a cart `span` in it. When the user hovers over it, it displays my hidden cart `DIV`. The user can then move the mouse to the `DIV` to remove an item.

If the user displays and moves the mouse into the hidden `DIV` then moves out of this, the `DIV` is re-hidden

The issue I'm having is that if the user displays the `DIV` but instead of moving into hidden `DIV`, goes back to the sub/main menu the `DIV` is not re-hiding and I have tried everything I can think of.

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/murday1983/2j8L3h47/20/).

If you don't go to the div first it won't hide it.

```js
$('#subMenuCartBox').mouseover(function () {
  $('#cartBox').show();
  $('#cartBox').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#cartBox').hide();
  });
}).mouseleave(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (!$('#cartBox').length) {
      $('#cartBox').hide();
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.mainMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.subMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

.subMenuOptionSpan {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.subMenuCartBox {
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cartBox {
    float: right;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: none;
    left: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainMenu">
  Main menu options
</div>

<div class="subMenu">
  <div class="row justify-content-end align-items-center">
    <span class="subMenuOptionSpan col-12 col-sm-auto">
      <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg"></i>
      <div id="username">Test of long username</div>
    </span>
    <span id="subMenuCartBox" class="subMenuOptionSpan col-12 col-sm-auto">
      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg"></i>
      <div id="cartAmountBox" class="subMenuCartBox">
        <span id="cartAmountText" class="subMenuCartAmount">0 item(s) - £0.00</span>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cartBox" class="cartBox">
  <b id="emptyCart">There are currently no items in your cart.</b>
</div>
```

I need the hidden `DIV` to re-hide if the user goes anywhere on the page without having to go inside it and then out of it.

Comment: Your fiddle was not set up correctly. Also please post code HERE instead of externally.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Wils - I need the hidden `DIV` to re-hide if the user goes anywhere on the page without having to go inside it and then out of it.

Comment: there are many div in your snippet, im confused which div you want to hide and which wont hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Jquery you can check on which side the mouse leaves the button and keep the div open when you leave the button on the bottom.

```
$('#subMenuCartBox').mouseover(function () {
  $('#cartBox').show();

  $('#subMenuCartBox').mouseleave(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var bottom = $this.offset().top + $this.outerHeight();
     if(e.pageY < bottom) {
      console.log("CLOSE");
      $('#cartBox').hide();
    }
  });

  $('#cartBox').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#cartBox').hide();
  });
}).mouseleave(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (!$('#cartBox').length) {
      $('#cartBox').hide();
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what i was after.  Most comments where just hidding the `DIV` as soon as i moved. You read it correct

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#subMenuCartBox').mouseover(function () {
  $('#cartBox').show();

}).mouseleave(function () {

      $('#cartBox').hide();
 
})
```

```css
.mainMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.subMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: gray;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px;
}

.subMenuOptionSpan {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.subMenuCartBox {
    background-color: deepskyblue;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.cartBox {
    float: right;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: none;
    left: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainMenu">
  Main menu options
</div>

<div class="subMenu">
  <div class="row justify-content-end align-items-center">
    <span class="subMenuOptionSpan col-12 col-sm-auto">
      <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg"></i>
      <div id="username">Test of long username</div>
    </span>
    <span id="subMenuCartBox" class="subMenuOptionSpan col-12 col-sm-auto">
      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg"></i>
      <div id="cartAmountBox" class="subMenuCartBox">
        <span id="cartAmountText" class="subMenuCartAmount">0 item(s) - £0.00</span>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cartBox" class="cartBox">
  <b id="emptyCart">There are currently no items in your cart.</b>
</div>
```

Do you mean you want to archive this? please clarify your question.

Comment: No. Doing this doesn't work as you cannot go into the `Div` if required to remove an item or click the button in the hidden `DIV` as i added in my post, i need ot be able to do this.  I know this as this was the first thing i tried

Comment: Which div you want to hide when mouseout?